# Why risk to rush to Achashverosh if the decree is due in 11 months?

Tags: pikuachnefesh-danger-life, megillat-esther

Someone related this question at the *s'udas Purim*:

*Haman*'s decree was promulgated on the 13th of *Nisan* and would not take effect until the 13th of *Adar* following. Yet, *Mord'chay* urged *Ester* to seek redress from *Achashverosh* immediately. This would not be surprising, except that she had told him she had not been called to *Achashverosh* in a month, so was risking her life: why not wait until she would be called (which would surely happen with time to spare before *Adar*)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Malbim (to 4:13-14) writes (translation taken from The Malbim Esther, by R. Jonathan Taub (Feldheim, 1998)):

> Mordechai informed Esther of several
>   fundamental principles: ...
>
> For any tragedy that befalls the Jews,
>   there is a specific time and day ready
>   for their deliverance by certain
>   prepared means. If these means are not
>   actualized, then the Omnipresent will
>   prepare other means to save them.
>
> ...
>
> Since Esther was granted her position
>   as queen only in order to help the
>   Jews, and since the date for their
>   salvation had already been determined,
>   if she did not act immediately she
>   might miss the appointed time and the
>   Almighty would use other agents to
>   effect their deliverance.

Answer (score 2):

I suggested (no source):

The *g'mara* (12:2, with *Rashi*) notes that, had *Achashverosh* not sent out the decree that men rule their homes, the gentiles would have killed out the Jews long before *Adar* in their zeal to comply with the law to do so. Only because they questioned their king (because of the earlier law) did they forbear. So perhaps *Mord'chay* was worried that the gentiles would not wait for *Adar*.

Answer (score 2):

Rav Chaim kanievsky in taima dikra answers because, people were so scared of the decree it was pikuach nefesh, so it had to be annulled right away.

Answer (score 1):

My father-in-law suggested (no source):

The *Y'rushalmi* (*B'rachos* 1:1) says "כך היא גאולתן של ישראל בתחילה קימאה קימאה", that redemption starts little by little (and the Jews' did at that time, what with the *Bigsan* story and all), so perhaps *Mord'chay* saw a need to start the process going although it was yet early.