# Why did Ester fast right away?

Tags: megillat-esther

B"H

After hearing about the decree, Ester became very worried and she wanted to tell the king right away about nullifying it, but she wasn't allowed to see him without permission, so she asked the entire Jewish people to fast for 3 days right away she she herself fasted then as well, in order to have Hashem's help to see the king at a time she wasn't allowed to

The question is, the decree was made in mid-nissan, for the next adar of the coming year, a long ways away

Why couldn't Ester have simply waited a few weeks or so to be called in to the king at a proper time, then ask him then to nullify it?

Comment: Keep in mind the decree was being sent out all over this massive empire, and was granting permission to people to randomly kill their Jewish neighbors. The longer the decree was out there, the more preparation these anti Semites would have. So we had to send out our anti decree as quick as possible to get the Jews themselves ready for the war

Comment: @CuriousYid yeah but we're talking A difference of like 3 weeks or so in the course of a year

Comment: Same question?https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/6454/why-risk-to-rush-to-achashverosh-if-the-decree-is-due-in-11-months?rq=1

Comment: @Shlomy yeah I didn't know about that

Answer (score 1):

Rav Chaim kanievsky in taima dikra answers because, people were so scared of the decree it was pikuach nefesh, so it had to be annulled right away.